# numpy dimensionally multiply an ndarray with an array of scalars

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an `ndarray` `A` of dimensions (2,3,4,5), and an arrays `B` and `C` of dimension 3, is there a way I can concisely multiply `A` with `B` and add `C` without a loop, such that:

```
for idx in range(len(B)):
    A[:,idx,:,:] = B[idx] * A[:,idx,:,:] + C[idx]
```

I imagine there should be a 1 line way of doing it that yields better performance. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your arrays `B` and `C` to have shape `(3, 1, 1)`. The additional reshaping to the shape of `A` will be performed by Numpy in form of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
A = A * B[:, None, None] + C[:, None, None]
```